# Managing threads accessing a database with Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sqlite, javafx

I am working on an app that accesses an SQLite database. The problem is the DB gets locked when there is a query to it. Most of the time this is not a problem because the flow of the app is quite linear.

However I have a very long calculation process which is triggered by the user. This process involves multiple calls to the database in between calculations.

I wanted the user to get some visual feedback so I have been using Javafx progressIndicator and a Service from the Javafx.Concurrency framework.
The problem is this leaves the user free to move around the app and potentially triggering other calls to the database.

This caused an exception that the database file is locked.
I would like a way to stop that thread from running when this case happens however I have not been able to find any clear examples online. Most of them are oversimplified and I would like a way which is scalable. I've tried using the cancel() method but this does not guarantee that the thread will be cancelled in time.

Because I am not able to check in all parts of the code for isCancelled sometimes there is a delay between the time the thread is canceled and the time it effectively stops.

So I thought of the following solution but I would like to know if there is a better way in terms of efficiency and avoiding race conditions and hanging.

```
    // Start service
    final CalculatorService calculatorService = new CalculatorService();

    // Register service with thread manager
    threadManager.registerService(CalculatorService);

    // Show the progress indicator only when the service is running
    progressIndicator.visibleProperty().bind(calculatorService.runningProperty());

calculatorService.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent workerStateEvent) {
            System.out.println("SUCCEEDED");
            calculatorService.setStopped(true);
        }
    });

    // If something goes wrong display message
    calculatorService.setOnFailed(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent workerStateEvent) {
            System.out.println("FAILED");
            calculatorService.setStopped(true);
        }
    });

    // Restart the service
    calculatorService.restart();
```

This is my service class which I have subclassed to include methods that can be used to set the state of the service (stopped or not stopped)

```
    public class CalculatorService extends Service implements CustomService {
    private AtomicBoolean stopped;
    private CalculatorService serviceInstance;

    public FindBundleService() {
        stopped = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        instance = this;
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Results> createTask() {
        return new Task<Result>() {

            @Override
            protected Result call() throws Exception {
                try {
                    Result = calculationMethod(this, serviceInstance);
                    return Result;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // If the thread is interrupted return
                    setStopped(true);
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStopped() {
        return stopped.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void setStopped(boolean stopped) {
        this.stopped.set(stopped);
    }
}
```

The service implements this interface which I defined

```
public interface CustomService {

    /**
     * Method to check if a service has been stopped
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isStopped();

    /**
     * Method to set a service as stopped
     * 
     * @param stopped
     */
    public void setStopped(boolean stopped);

}
```

All services must register themselves with the thread manager which is a singleton class.

```
public class ThreadManager {

    private ArrayList<CustomService> services;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public ThreadManager() {
        services = new ArrayList<CustomService>();
    }

    /**
     * Method to cancel running services
     */
    public boolean cancelServices() {
        for(CustomService service : services) {
            if(service.isRunning()) {
                ((Service) service).cancel();
                while(!service.isStopped()) {
                    // Wait for it to stop
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Method to register a service
     */
    public void registerService(CustomService service) {
        services.add(service);
    }

    /**
     * Method to remove a service
     */
    public void removeService(CustomService service) {
        services.remove(service);
    }

}
```

In any place in the app if we want to stop the service we call cancelServices(). This will set the state to cancelled I'm checking for this in my calculationMethod() then setting the state to stopped just before returning (effectively ending the thread).

```
if(task.isCancelled()) {
        service.setStopped(true);
        return null;
}
```

Comment: Why multiple calls to the db? Why not get all the info you need in one call?

Comment: Thats because we are doing some calculations based on what we received from the DB then using the results to get other things from the DB. Its a business logic which I cant change.

Comment: I would disable all `Nodes` that would trigger another call to the db until the `task` has finished.

Comment: That was my initial idea. However the process is quite long and I want the user to be able to interrupt it i.e by going to another part of the tab.

Comment: Create a `Button` and make its purpose interrupting the `task` and enabling the `Nodes`.

Comment: All other `Nodes` can still be used as long as they don't make a call to the db.

Comment: Perhaps I can create that button. But my question is about how to implement the functionality for interrupting the tasks. The method I've shown works but I don't know if it has potential issues or if there is a more acceptable way.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418033/java-executors-how-can-i-stop-submitted-tasks) may help.

Comment: if i am following you,, [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) may help

Comment: You whish to block the actions that require db access when you are running this calculation? Or you wish to cancel the current calculation and perform the new action requested by the user?

Comment: @Arthur. Cancel the current action and perform the new action

Comment: Are you using JDBC for your queries? `PreparedStatement` has a [`cancel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#cancel()) method to cancel a potentially-long running query.

Answer (score 3):

(I will assume you are using JDBC for your database queries and that you have control over the code running the queries)

I would centralize all database accesses in a singleton class which would keep the last `PreparedStatement` running the current query in a single thread [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). You could then ask that singleton instance things like `isQueryRunning()`, `runQuery()`, `cancelQuery()` that would be `synchronized` so you can decide to show a message to the user whenever the computation should be canceled, cancel it and start a new one.

Something like (add null checks and `catch (SQLException e)` blocks):

```
public class DB {

    private Connection cnx;
    private PreparedStatement lastQuery = null;
    private ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); // So you execute only one query at a time

    public synchronized boolean isQueryRunning() {
        return lastQuery != null;
    }

    public synchronized Future<ResultSet> runQuery(String query) {
        // You might want to throw an Exception here if lastQuery is not null (i.e. a query is running)
        lastQuery = cnx.preparedStatement(query);
        return exec.submit(new Callable<ResultSet>() {
            public ResultSet call() {
                try {
                    return lastQuery.executeQuery();
                } finally { // Close the statement after the query has finished and return it to null, synchronizing
                    synchronized (DB.this) {
                        lastQuery.close();
                        lastQuery = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Or wrap the above Future<ResultSet> so that Future.cancel() will actually cancel the query
    }

    public synchronized void cancelQuery() {
        lastQuery.cancel(); // I hope SQLite supports this
        lastQuery.close();
        lastQuery = null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution to your problem **could** be `Thead.stop()`, which has been deprecated *centuries* ago (you can find more on the topic [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)).

To implement the similar behavior it is suggested to use the `Thread.interrupt()`, which is (in the context of `Task`) the same as the the `Task.cancel()`.

Solutions:

- Fill your `calculationMethod` with `isCancelled()` checks.
- Try to interrupt an underling operation through an other `Thread`.

The second solution is probably what you are looking for, but it depends on the actual code of the `calculationMethod` (which I guess you can't share).

Generic examples for killing long database operations (all of this are performed from another thread):

- Kill the connection to the Database (assuming that the Database is smart enough to kill the operation on disconnect and then unlock the database).
- Ask for the Database to kill an operation (eg. `kill <SPID>`).

**EDIT:**

I hadn't see that that you specified the database to SQLite when I wrote my answer. So to specify the solutions for SQLite:

- Killing the connection will not help
- Look for the equivalent of [sqlite3_interrupt](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/interrupt.html) in your java SQLite interface

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can invoke thread instance t1, t1.interrupt() method, then in the run method of thread( Maybe calculationMethod), add a conditional statement.

```
 public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                // my code goes here
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                log.error(ex,ex)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With WAL mode (write-ahead logging) you can do many queries in parallel to the sqlite database

> WAL provides more concurrency as readers do not block writers and a
>   writer does not block readers. Reading and writing can proceed
>   concurrently.

https://sqlite.org/wal.html

Perhaps these links are of interest to you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6654908/1989579
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlcipher/4pE_XAE14TY
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16205732/1989579